# Bootstrap, navbar white spaces left and right. Margin: 0; not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This navbar is causing a significantly white space on left and right side. I've tried margin: 0; but it doesen't respond to it. I've already got a navbar that look like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-left">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                Menu <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="Handler?action=mainPage">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Handler?action=logOut">Log out</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Handler?action=profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Handler?action=eventManager">Manager</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the one above does not cause any trouble. So it seems odd to me that another one nearly equal should.

```
           <div class="navbar navbar-inverse hidden-lg" id="tea">
                <div class="container-left">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".bot12">
                        Menu <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bot12">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <li><a href="Handler?action=mainPage">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Handler?action=logOut">Log out</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Handler?action=profile">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Handler?action=eventManager">Manager</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation and use `<div class="container-fluid"></div>`

Comment: Can you show the issue in a fiddle? I tried the above HTML at my end and it seems to look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "significant whitespace" issue on your navbar is caused by you missing the `navbar-static-top` or `navbar-fixed-top` on your markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hidden-lg" id="tea">
  <div class="container-left">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target=".bot12">
      Menu <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bot12">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="Handler?action=mainPage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Handler?action=logOut">Log out</a></li>
        <li><a href="Handler?action=profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="Handler?action=eventManager">Manager</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding that removes the whitespace and fixes the rounded corners (which aren't supposed to be there).

[Booyply Example](http://www.bootply.com/lu93hF0mRM)